# Simultaneously creating internal and external linkages in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer, extern, internal-link

I was reading a C reference about linkage (external, internal and none) and came across the following:

> If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both
> internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

I wanted to know how this undefined behavior can occur. Based on what I had read, a variable can have only one storage class. So it cannot be declared both `static` and `extern` at the same time.

So in what scenario can a variable have both internal and external linkage?

Comment: Well, you can declare the same function multiple times; and you have the definition vs the declaration. Maybe that's the intention? Just speculating, IANALL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
extern int x;
static int x;
```

The first declaration says `x` has external linkage, and the second declaration says it has internal linkage.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify. It doesn't compile if I put both `extern int x` and `static int x` in the same scope. It compiles if I declare a static global variable and use the extern keyword inside `main()`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry. It does compiles if I declare it static first and then extern (both declared in global scope). Thanks for the answer

Comment: @AbhayAravinda: `extern` and `static` have different effects depending on where they appear. If an identifier is declared `extern` after an earlier declaration with internal or external linkage, the new declaration just copies the old; it will not change a declaration with internal linkage to external. (If the earlier declaration specifies no linkage, the new declaration makes a new identifier with external linkage.) If an identifier is declared with `static` in block scope, it has no linkage.

Comment: So `extern int x; static int x;` gives `x` two linkages, violating the rules, since the first declaration has external linkage. But `static int x; extern int x;` does not violate the rules, since the second declaration leaves the internal linkage.